# Where can I find Microsoft Sql Profiler 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-profiler

Is there a way to get the profiler without installing Microsoft Sql Server?

If the answer is no, which edition do I need to get the profiler?  Do I need the Developer Edition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will need at least the Developer Edition (Express edition does not include the profiler).

However, you do *not* have to install the database server itself in order to use the profiler. You will want to look for something called something like "Client tools" in the installer.

Depending on your needs, you might be able to use a third-party profiler instead, such as the open-source [SQL Server Express Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler/) from AnjLab.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the open source AnjLab [profiler](http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler) if you are using an express edition of sql server. It's pretty powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install management studio express.